# how to tell that that recycler view should not recycle some particular view type

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

i am playing video from youtube api using recycler view, When ever i scroll up and down.The player will be restarting automatically

```
recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews(VIDEO, 0);
```

but this is not working , any help?

Comment: override `Adapter#onViewRecycled`

Comment: pskink its not working. I removed super method for video type.

Comment: `onViewRecycled` is not called? what does it mean: `"not working"`?

Comment: pskink onview recycled called. But what to with that. I did not pass super method when holder is  video item .But still its recycling the view i think, whenever i scroll up and down , on bind video is called again

Comment: so if its called then save the current playing position and use it later when `onBindViewHolder` is called again

Comment: saving position is not problem. i have tried. But audio is playing video appears in black screen

Comment: so stop it in `onViewRecycled`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151280/discussion-between-asthme-and-pskink).

Comment: @pskink i have tried. sorry internet connection is bad here

Comment: what did you try?